# Doctrine 2 Orm ManyToOne with unsigned foreign keys

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, symfony

I'm using Symfony3 with Doctrine ORM 2 Annotations.

I generated entities from an existing MySQL database. I also wrote all the relations.
Before updating the Database I schema I used the command

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I have all the primary keys with INT unsigned so the related foreign keys too.
Now I noted that Doctrine ORM doesn't allow to use the

```
options={"unsigned":true}
```

in

```
@JoinColumn
```

So how can I solve this issue ?
Do I have to let Doctrine rewrite all the keys ?
I dont' know what way to follow to avoid damage to the DB and data.

Comment: Why do you need ```options={"unsigned":true}``` in ```@JoinColumn```? It will use column definition from the referenced entity.

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko is correct, doctrine should automatically use the definition of the referenced entity's column. If you want to override this you can use `columnDefinition='...'` but that's usually a bad idea, because it loses portability.

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to say what concrete type you want. Doctrine will do automaticaly when it will create your tables.
If you want migrate from current tables (int -> int) to new tables format (unsigned int -> unsigned int) you can make a few additional migration commands:

1. Drop current foreign key.
2. Change type of columns for your tables
3. Create foreign key for your tables.

You can do it manual or use migration with this commands.
I hope, this will help all people with the similar problem.